# Arduino Yun, pass int data true REST

Tags: arduino-yun

Would it be possible to instead of passing a state via a REST browser:

```
digital/13/1
```

to set an int value? For example, if in the sketch if I would name an int: 2, could I set this to 48 via REST?

If so, how?

Comment: Just to be perfectly clear, it is illegal in C++ to have a variable name start with (or be) a number.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [TemperatureWebPanel](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/TemperatureWebPanel) example: you'll see that you can make your own REST APIs and pass any values your sketch can handle.